# Export the default system email text to code?

Tags: 7, emails

Is it possible to move the default system email message text found in the account settings page out of the database and into the code for version control?

Currently using the mimemail module since we use HTML/CSS formatted emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings in files for version control was one of the biggest changes in the 7 -> 8 jump. Drupal 7 has no built-in way to do it. You may wish to see [How to version control data stored in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2751808).

If you want Drupal-specific tool, investigate [Configuration Management](https://drupal.org/project/configuration) module:

> The configuration management module enables the ability to keep track of specific configurations on a Drupal site, provides the ability to move these configurations between different environments (local, dev, qa, prod), and also move configurations between completely different sites (migrate configurations) without the use of modules with all configuration being owned by the site.

Comment: Interesting, we use features but never heard of this one. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Cromian This module is designed to work where features are just too much. Well, actually it's about a year older, but anyway.  Configuration Management is for situations when you need just something to manage configuration, Features is to create self-contained packages, and for configuration management they are a bit of overkill